# if condition in PHP is not working

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have added an **if** in the below php code, where I need to check if the entry exists or not in a mysql DB.

The variable in the **if** statement is null and the **else** is not working, and keeps echoing  a blank line. Any idea?

```
<?php

include ('config/config.php');

$dir = '/home/masteryoda/certs';
$sql = "select * from certificates";

 if (is_dir($dir)){
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
         while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
             if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                $files = $dir."/".$file;

                $data = openssl_x509_parse(file_get_contents($files));

                $validFrom = date('Y-m-d', $data['validFrom_time_t']);
                $validTo = date('Y-m-d', $data['validTo_time_t']);
                $common = $data['subject']['CN'];
                $issuer = $data['issuer']['CN'];

                $res = $conn->query($sql);

                while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    if ( $common == $row['CommonName'] && $validFrom == $row['ValidFrom'] && $validTo == $row['ValidTo'] )
                    {

                        echo "Vars:".$common."".$row['CommonName']."".$validFrom."".$row['ValidFrom']."".$validTo."".$row['ValidTo'];
                        echo "Certificate exists";
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $result = $conn->query("insert into certificates  (CommonName,ValidTo,ValidFrom,Issuer) values ('$common','$validTo','$validFrom','$issuer')");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
 }
```

Comment: _What_ variables are null? `$common`? `$row['CommonName']`? Have you tried doing a `print_r($row);` above the if statement?

Comment: Corrected formulation and added some formatting

Answer (score -1):

Try to use !empty() function.

```
if (!empty($row)) {
    echo "Vars:" . $common . "" . $row['CommonName'] . "" . $validFrom . "" . $row['ValidFrom'] . "" . $validTo . "" . $row['ValidTo'];
    echo "Certificate exists";
} else {
    $result = $conn->query("insert into certificates  (CommonName,ValidTo,ValidFrom,Issuer) values ('$common','$validTo','$validFrom','$issuer')");
}
```

Comment: Od comment, but he iterate in PHP for all results in DB. In you solution, if he have any certificate in DB, then won't add any new.

Comment: The empty value did the work. Thank you. I think we can consider it as solved.

Comment: @GeorgeKapellakis if you think my solution is helpful for you then select it as your answer.

Comment: @timiTao #George said my solution is helpful for him. But can you please let me know what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: SQL : `$sql = "select * from certificates";` the he check all certificate in DB. Then if any record exists in DB, then empty will always return false and create insert. If he have empty DB, then it will not add new records. What is he have some certificates in DB, but want to add new? How then, is you only check is records is empty? I assume, he had some records in DB, but didn't add new.  I think, you didn't fix the code, but resolve one bug, creating another.

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).